# jqgrid validation routine errors in jqgrid library script for b(":input:visible", a.w)[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqgrid

I'm using a custom function to validate my jqgrid.  The users wish to enter hours worked in a day as `Hour:Minute` format (e.g., 7:30, 8:00).  The validation rule needs to return false whenever a work day exceeds 20 hours and 1 minute. The validation function works in that it flags the error, but firebug displays a 2nd error:  `b(":input:visible", a.w)[0] is undefined, and points to line 379 in the library (version 4.1.2)`.

Help is appreciated!

Here's the grid and the custom validation:

```
 WorkSchedule.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.jqgridParms = {
        datatype: "local",
        height: 'auto',
        width: 700,
        colNames: ["Week", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Total"],
        colModel: [// very much dummy stuff here.
                    {name: "Week", index: "Week", width: 50, editable: false },
                   { name: "Sun", index: "Sun", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                       dataInit: function(elem) {
                           $(elem).mask("99:99");
                       }
                   }, align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                   },
                    { name: "Mon", index: "Mon", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                        dataInit: function(elem) {
                            $(elem).mask("99:99");
                        }
                    }, align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                    },
                    { name: "Tues", index: "Tues", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                        dataInit: function(elem) {
                            $(elem).mask("99:99");
                        }
                    },
                        align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                    },
                    { name: "Wed", index: "Wed", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                        dataInit: function(elem) {
                            $(elem).mask("99:99");
                        }
                    },
                        align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                    },
                    { name: "Thurs", index: "Thurs", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                        dataInit: function(elem) {
                            $(elem).mask("99:99");
                        }
                    },
                        align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                    },
                    { name: "Fri", index: "Fri", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                        dataInit: function(elem) {
                            $(elem).mask("99:99");
                        }
                    },
                        align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                    },
                    { name: "Sat", index: "Sat", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                        dataInit: function(elem) {
                            $(elem).mask("99:99");
                        }
                    },
                        align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                    },
                    { name: "WeekTotal", index: "WeekTotal", width: 55, editable: true, align: "center" }
                  ],
        multiselect: false,
        caption: "Manage Work Schedule",
        rowNum: 10,
        cellEdit: true,
        gridComplete: function() {
            calculateTotal();
        },
        beforeSaveCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
            formatFromMask(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol);
        },
        afterSaveCell: function() {
            calculateTotal();
        },
        cellsubmit: "clientArray"
    }
}




function validHourEntry(value, colname) {
    var editSuccess = true;

    var errorMsg = "";

    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        editSuccess = false;
        errorMsg = colname + " entry is required";
    }
    else if (value.length == 0) {
        editSuccess = false;
        errorMsg = colname + " entry is required";
    }

    else {
    value = value.replace(/_/g, "0");   
        var hourMinSplit = value.lastIndexOf(":");
        var hours = value.substring(0, hourMinSplit);
        var mins = value.substring(hourMinSplit + 1, value.length);
        if (isNaN(hours)) {
            editSuccess = false;
            errorMsg = "The value for hours must be numeric";
        }   
        else if (isNaN(mins)) {
            editSuccess = false;
            errorMsg = "The value for minutes must be numeric";
        }
        else if (Number(hours) * 60 + Number(mins) > 1200) {
            editSuccess = false;
            errorMsg = "Work day entry must not exceed 20 hours and 00 minutes";
        }
    }
    return [editSuccess, errorMsg];
}

function createWorkScheduleData(rowID) {

    if (rowID == 0) {
        return [ //goofy dummy data so I can test.
                {Week: "Week 1", Sun: "00:00", Mon: "00:00", Tues: "00:00", Wed: "00:00", Thurs: "00:00", Fri: "00:00", Sat: "00:00" },
                { Week: "Week 2", Sun: "00:00", Mon: "00:00", Tues: "00:00", Wed: "00:00", Thurs: "00:00", Fri: "00:00", Sat: "00:00"}];
    }
    else if (rowID == 1) {
        return [{ Week: "Week 1", Sun: "00:00", Mon: "08:00", Tues: "08:00", Wed: "08:00", Thurs: "08:00", Fri: "08:00", Sat: "00:00" },
    {
        Week: "Week 2", Sun: "00:00", Mon: "08:00", Tues: "08:00", Wed: "08:00", Thurs: "08:00", Fri: "08:00", Sat: "00:00"
    }
    ];
    }
    else if (rowID == 2) {
        return [{ Week: "Week 1", Sun: "00:00", Mon: "04:00", Tues: "04:00", Wed: "04:00", Thurs: "04:00", Fri: "04:00", Sat: "00:00" },
    {
        Week: "Week 2", Sun: "00:00", Mon: "04:00", Tues: "04:00", Wed: "04:00", Thurs: "04:00", Fri: "04:00", Sat: "00:00"
    }
    ];
    }
    else if (rowID == 3) {
        return [{ Week: "Week 1", Sun: "00:00", Mon: "07:30", Tues: "07:30", Wed: "07:30", Thurs: "07:30", Fri: "07:30", Sat: "00:00" },
    {
        Week: "Week 2", Sun: "00:00", Mon: "07:30", Tues: "07:30", Wed: "07:30", Thurs: "07:30", Fri: "07:30", Sat: "00:00"
    }
    ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be an issue with Firebug, not with jqgrid.  I'm posting this in case others get the same behavior. I turned off Firebug and my validation worked as expected. It also works with chrome and IE without any javascript errors.  Annoyed I didn't think of trying it before posting the question, but happy it's not a real issue.